# A finite group acting on a torsion-free group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, torsion-groups

I'm trying the following problem

> Let $G$ be a group. $H, K$ subgroups of $G$, where $|K|=m$, $H$ is torsion-free and $[G:H]=n$. Prove that $m\leq n$ and $m\mid n$.

The hint: Use some group action of $K$ over $G/H$.

I tried to use the action defined by left multiplication of cosets in $G/H$ by elements of $K$ (I guess it's the natural action), but I can't conclude anything useful.

Can someone suggest any idea?

Comment: What is $T$? ${}$

Comment: My mistake, T is K.

Answer (score 1):

2nd hint : Show that the natural action of $K$ on $G/H$ is free.

Comment: I proved that. The missing part is the divisibility

Comment: @ÁngelaFlores, do you know the second class formula?

Comment: What is that? I've never heard about that

Comment: @ÁngelaFlores, it does not really matter, it is a very cheap shortcut in the context anyway. What you shall do: first justify that all $K$-orbits of $G/H$ have cardinal $m$ and then conclude.

Comment: Thank you! That worked